# Why my application shows two Add/Remove icons in Control Panel in XP and Vista?

Tags: windows, installation, installshield, installation-package

To avoid admin privileges problem in "Change" option from Control Panel, I edited "NoRepair" and "NoModify" registry entries to use the value `1` and "WindowsInstaller" to use `0`. By doing this, I am getting full UI when uninstalling from Control Panel.

But here is the problem: by setting "WindowsInstaller" to `0`, Control Panel shows two Add/Remove icons of my application in Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Comment: What admin privileges problem? Can you give us more details about the actual problem you are encountering? What you did with the registry entries is some sort of hack and not a real solution.

Comment: I provide option for deleting files while uninstall, but "Change/Modify" option doesn't require admin rights, so if user select "Chabge/Modify" and go for uninstall with delete file option, it showed some Fetal error.
So i edit registry, add "NoRepair" and "NoModify" key with value 1
and set "WindowsInstaller" value to 0 under "Uninstall" root for my application.
But this works fine in Windows 7, not in XP and Vista.
It shows two icons of my application in control panel, one uninstalls by UninstallString, which one i need, but another uninstalls with windows installer which i want to Hide.

Comment: Is that option enforced by a custom action? If it is, just make sure that the custom action is deferred with no impersonation. The uninstall process requires the same privileges as the install process. So if you can create the files during install, a deferred with no impersonation action can remove those files during uninstall.

Comment: Custom action is deferred and it works fine in windows 7,
but not in XP and Vista... It shows two icons in control panel...
if i uninstall one of them, then both are removed.....

Answer (score 0):

I work around this issue for sometime, and found one solution...

I add one property "ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" with value "1" in my basic MSI project, thus all control panel icons of applications were removed...

Then i add another registry key for my application under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" with desired uninstallstring and without "WindowsInstaller" key...

Thus it shows only one icon in control panel, and also the behaviour of uninstallation is as i needed....